# As a jungler when should I push the lane after a gank?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm getting fairly confidant in ganking abilities as a jungler. However, sometimes I don't know what I should do following a gank. This is what I typically do now for early/mid game ganks:

1. Both my team mate and enemy laner are dead/recalled: I clear current wave then head back into jungle.
2. Enemy laner is dead/recalled, team mate is alive: I will leave and let my laner farm (I don't usually tax the lane as some players get angry and I don't play junglers that require expensive builds).
3. My team mate is dead/recalled and the enemy laner remains: I stay around to protect the tower and not let exp go to waste until team mate returns.

This makes sense to me but I'm wondering if this is ideal in the general sense. Certain circumstances can change priorities but is this a good start?

Comment: I think you have a good answer there. Only suggestion i'd make is on 1, if the wave is pushing against your team, it may be better to let it push assuming your dead/recalled teammates will make it back before it hits your tower. Also a 4, if you're about to go for dragon push the wave and then go do dragon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your original question:

## Clearing waves is bad in some cases.

By just clearing the current wave, you are allowing the minions on your team to push closer to their turret. If their champion is capable of freezing the lane, this will put your buddy at a disadvantageous position if the wave you cleared was in the middle of the lane.

### In general, you want to do one of the following if both are dead:

- Last hit the current wave or simply leave. (If the lane is neutral)
- Push the wave up to the tower and make the tower kill one or two of your waves. (This is to reset the lane, the closer minions are to pushing into an enemy tower, the more priority you should give this.)
- Clear part of a wave so they don't push into your own tower. (To prevent resetting the lane in the enemy's favour)

In other words, it depends on the situation, but a general rule is that you want to keep the lane as close to your side of the map as possible, and as the game drags on (if you are winning) you want to shift that balance from your side to their side more and more, so you can start putting pressure and forcing down turrets.

### If the enemy is alive:

You either want to:

- Keep the lane so that you don't lose a turret as fast. (This is mostly true for strong pushing champs)*
- Leave the lane if the enemy is weak at pushing if you can do more beneficial stuff. (Get / give buffs, secure dragon, gank another lane, whatever)
- Kill the enemy champ. (If you think you can do so)

*Note: In some cases it is recommended to let your tower get destroyed, if the player who is laning against an enemy is performing *really* bad. Letting the tower get destroyed allows the minions to get pushed into your side of the map even further, allowing the bad laner to freeze his lane at the second turret and farm there. (Of course, you should pay attention at this point because otherwise you're just giving away turrets)

### If teammate is alive but enemy is dead:

Either:

- Leave and let him continue farming.
- Help him push down the turret.*
- (Situational, mostly for bot-ganks) Kill Dragon

*: Pushing down turrets at botlane can be especially helpful as it allows you to pressure them more, thus giving you more leeway to take dragon out, as they can't permit to stay close to it if they don't maintain vision of the river and jungle 24/7.

---

Also, if there are other lanes that you can gank right away, you should of course do that instead of just farming minions for your buddy. A few minions aren't worth as much as another kill + assist.

And as a closing note: Ultimately it also sort of depends on the champion composition. Sometimes you have a team (or jungler) that is capable of pressuring a lot more than the enemy team, in which case again, you want to push up a bit more so you can take more control of the map, sooner.

Comment: Just want to mention one thing that really irritates me. DON'T TAX THE LANER. It happens to me all the time and is incredibly annoying. My jungler will just walk through and gank horribly then force my lane up (I like to freeze just before turret in most cases) and take/screw up an entire wave. The only time its "ok" to stay in the lane is if you're pushing to take the turret, outside of that let us farm :)

Comment: I would only comment that a *really bad laner* probably doesn't even know what "freeze the lane" means, let alone be able to do it.

Comment: @Almo I agree when it concerns *really bad laners*. When writing that down I wasn't merely thinking about unskilled players though, but bad champion matchups in general. I guess I could've made that a little more clear.

Comment: @ZeroStatic yup. Good answer though!

Comment: I disagree with @slow_excellence with the imperative "DON'T TAX THE LANER" thing. Taxing is important to keeping the jungler's exp and gold levels at par with everyone else. The jungle gives his/her time to gank your lane to help you out. If the gank is successful, then taxes aren't necessary because he got his time's worth. If a gank is unsuccessful, 1-3 creeps is a fine tax to pay. Because if you don't, you're just leaving YOUR OWN TEAMMATE (I repeat, YOUR OWN TEAMMATE, THIS IS A TEAM GAME), very much behind.

Comment: There is a right way of taxing, and a wrong way. Junglers who make a successful gank don't need to take the whole creep wave after that. Now it's the inverse, you're (the jungler) putting your teammate (mid/whatever lane) behind now.

Sources : Diamond 3 Support main

Comment: I did put a little too much emphasis on that and I do agree with you mark. The only reason I say that is because I've had tons of junglers screw up waves of ~10 minions while I'm in lane only to last hit 1 or 2 of them, or they tax after taking a kill I've secured. Either way I try to avoid taxing when I jungle, the most I'll do is freeze at river or push for the turret. A lot of this is situational and I didn't elaborate enough on my side. Sorry about that!

Comment: Well, taxing ~10 minions is too much. :)) Anyway, our best long-term option is to coach them while gaming, which is what I'm doing with my smurf. :D Granted, not all of them will listen, but at least I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

When to push:

(Enemy laner is dead OR forced to back) AND (The lane will end up moving in the enemies direction OR Your teammate wishes to back quickly also)

This gives you 100% the time you want to push and this should be the **ONLY** time you ever tax.

Times you **DO NOT** want to push.

The lane can be frozen easily on your laners side AND your laner wishes to keep it frozen.

In the time to push, this part is the most important **(Enemy laner is dead OR forced to back)**.  If this is true, do not tax or push or your laner has every right to be pissed at you.

The second part of the **AND** clause is a little less clear:  **(The lane will end up moving in the enemies direction OR Your teammate wishes to back quickly also)**  Basically, if the wave is beginning a slow push towards the enemy turret, make it a fast push so it gets there before the enemy is back to lane.  If it can be frozen and your laner wishes to keep it frozen, **DO NOT TAX** or push.

One key thing that throws out the rules.  If an enemy is missing AND you are low health do not push.

So fully:

(Enemy laner is dead OR forced to back) AND (The lane will end up moving in the enemies direction OR Your teammate wishes to back quickly also) AND (You have high health OR no enemies are missing)

Comment: May want to revisit formatting as it made for a hard read(or maybe my reading ability is going down with age) but the overall answer was good. It may be worth adding in objectives aka you want to take dragon, or they're 3 man pushing the top lane and you're bottom etc

Comment: @Brian Yea, I might update it later.  I sort of rushed it since I'm at work.